# Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 update error

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, 20.04, update-manager

How can I fix this error? I tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-fast update
sudo apt-fast upgrade
```

These two commands ended successfully.

```
sudo update-manager -c -d
```

When it was running my internet got down, so I had to stop the process by pressing Ctrl+C.

I tried to run it again and got a TypeError:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 239, in _on_finished
    trans_failed=trans_failed)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/__init__.py", line 323, in _action_done
    self.window_main.duplicate_packages = self.get_deb2snap_dups()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/__init__.py", line 127, in get_deb2snap_dups
    if (deb in cache and cache[deb].is_installed):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 350, in __contains__
    return self.__is_real_pkg(self._cache[key])
TypeError: Expected a string or a pair of strings
```

During handling of the above exception, another TypeError occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 246, in _on_finished
    error_string=error_string, error_desc=error_desc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/__init__.py", line 323, in _action_done
    self.window_main.duplicate_packages = self.get_deb2snap_dups()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/__init__.py", line 127, in get_deb2snap_dups
    if (deb in cache and cache[deb].is_installed):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 350, in __contains__
    return self.__is_real_pkg(self._cache[key])
TypeError: Expected a string or a pair of strings
```

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` when you interrupted it you broke it.

Comment: I restarted system apt-fast update && apt-fast upgrade and
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade 

and it worked. Thank you for the response.

Comment: No worries. Please accept the **Answer** below (icons on the LHS) so that other ssearching for similar problems can find a solutuion.

Answer (score 0):

To repair the broken/interrupted package, at a terminal type

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first use `apt install -f` before `dpkg --configure -a` to fix broken packages.

Pressing Ctrl+C is really a bad idea, especially when you are doing distro-upgrade...

Packages one downloaded will install without the need of internet... and the upgrade process might reload or stop/start the network if it is upgrading it...